# Can you name a Django app: urls

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I'm trying to use this line in urls.py:

```
from mysite.urls.views import Index
```

However, Django is saying

```
ImportError at / 
No module named views
```

I think that is because it's going into /mysite/mysite/urls.py and not /mysite/urls/views.py

The structure is like this (omitted the uninvolved files):

```
mysite/
    templates/
    mysite/
        settings.py
        urls.py
    urls/
        views.py
    manage.py
```

Comment: try `from urls.views import index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that was my problem. I followed [How to change the name of a Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408046/how-to-change-the-name-of-a-django-app) and my problems went away. Long story short, don't name your app: urls.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute imports may be what you need:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Credits to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4931577/1028012

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty `__init__.py` inside your `urls` folder. Why that should work? Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448271/1904584) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Answer is correct but it's great if you'll add additional description why this file is necessary for better understanding.

Comment: @daniula, thanks for the tip. I have edited my answer, hope that helps.