# (Unexpected) TypeError while using setworldcoordinates()

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a canvas using Tkinter with a customized coordinates to be used in Turtle Graphics. The method [setworldcoordinates()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.setworldcoordinates) takes in four parameters and I did it as usual. Not sure why there is a TypeError here.

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle

master = Tk()
cv = Canvas(master, width = 200, height = 200)
screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(cv)

screen.setworldcoordinates(-50, -50, 50, 50)
```

This is the error message that I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(file path)\temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    screen.setworldcoordinates(-50, -50, 50, 50)
  File "(file path)\turtle.py", line 1095, in setworldcoordinates
    self.screensize(wx-20, wy-20)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: it seems it has strings in `wx`, `wy` and now it can't substract `20` from strings. Maybe it is abug in code. Or TurtleScreen needs special canvas which keeps these values as integers but normal Canvas use strings.

Comment: in error message you should have full path to file `turtle.py`  which has problem with setworldcoordinates. You can open this file in editor and check how it works.

Comment: @furas What I usually do after importing turtle is just `turtle.setworldcoordinates()` and input the four parameters it requires, and it works fine. But this time, I am trying to set coordinates in a different way by initiating a new canvas using Tkinter, maybe it has something to do with it.

Comment: Can confirm. I'm getting the same error as the OP. I'm running Python 3.7.3 with `python3-tk` installed.

Comment: I checked code in `turtle.py` - `turtle.setworldcoordinates()` gets values form `screen._window_size()` which returns strings instead of integers. Maybe Tutrle use modificed functions in its canvas and original canvas gives strings instead of integers.

Comment: I checked `screen._window_size()` - it gets `cv['width']`, `cv['height']` but `tkinter.Canvas` gives strings

Comment: canvas gives integers in turtles when canvas is embeded in windo - ie. `cv.pack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in source code I found that it uses different methods to get Canvas's size.

If `Canvas` is not embedded in window (not attached to layout/geometry manager) then it uses

```
cv['width'], cv['height']
```

which gives size as strings.

If `Canvas` is embed in window then it uses

```
cv.winfo_width(), cv.winfo_height()
```

which gives size as numbers

You have to use i.e.

```
cv.pack()
```

or

```
cv.grid()
```

to resolve problem.

But it will not work with `cv.place()`

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle

master = Tk()

cv = Canvas(master, width=200, height=200)
cv.pack() # <-- solution

screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(cv)

screen.setworldcoordinates(-50, -50, 50, 50)
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, that solves the problem. Quick question, could you please give an explanation on why `cv.pack()` or `cv.grid()` works but `cv.place()` doesn't?

Comment: `place()` doesn't resize widget when you resize window. `pack()` and `grid()` can automatically resize widgets so they need function which calculate new size when you resize window. And this function can makes difference.

Answer (score -2):

The name of the script should not be the same as a module you are importing. 
See also [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931487/how-to-import-python-module-with-same-filename-that-is-already-imported)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't mention it that the current file that I'm working with is `temp.py` whereas the second file `turtle.py` is actually the module itself.

Comment: I checked source code - problem is in module - `setworldcoordinates` uses `screen._window_size()` which returns value as text but `setworldcoordinates` treats it as integers.